# Pass event along with parameters to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I have this function:

```
 function openQv(lookHash,slideHash){
         console.log(lookHash)
         console.log(slideHash)

   .......
}
```

On page load I call it like so:

```
 openQv(lookHash,slideHash);
```

but I also call it when a user clicks an element like so, but in this I don't need to pass any parameters.

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-qv', openQv);
```

Now, I'm not sure how to add the `e.preventDefault();` for this case, for when the user clicks to provide jump to the top of the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [jQuery `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) yet? It should get you started.

Comment: The first argument to `openQv`, which you named `lookHash` will actually be the `e` you are talking about..

Comment: jQuery calls your function with the `event` object as the first parameter. So in your case the event will be in `lookHash`. Quick fix: `function openQv(e, lookHash, slideHash)`. When you call it directly pass a `null` and inside do a `if(e) e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv thanks but I get "e.preventDefault is not a function" if I do that

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv in that case how do I call the function on page load?  openQv(e,lookHash,slideHash); ?

Comment: Pass `null` for `event` and "inside do a `if(e) e.preventDefault()`".

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv that worked!

Answer (score 5):

There is no workaround, you'll have to wrap the call to `openQv` in a function that is calling `event.preventDefault()` first:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-qv', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    openQv();
});
```